# How do I create a Visual Studio solution using powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to create a powershell script that allows one to create a Visual Studio project or solution.

For example:

In powershell: create new Solution Name

Outcome: new Solution with Name = Solution Name

Comment: Please post what code you currently have and prepare a precise and answerable question. Stackoverflow is not a service to have programs written for you. You can have a look here for what makes a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Open a Powershell or DOS session, type the following:

```
dotnet new sln --name <solutionName>
```

For more details, give Andrew Lock's article [Creating and Edition Solution Files with the Net CLI](https://andrewlock.net/creating-and-editing-solution-files-with-the-net-cli/) a read.